# Some questions about functions with a class type

Tags: c++, function, class, member, member-access

So I am using C++ and experimenting with classes. I am trying to create a function with a class type. Here is the code:

```
struct action{
void setup(std::string){
/*...*/
}
};
action move(){
setup("*");//<-error:[use of undeclared identifier 'setup']
}
```

Can the instance function of the class access its member functions and objects? Also, what should it return? Do i have to create a seperate action instance to return? Can it be related to the `action move`?Thanks!

Comment: `move()` is not a member of the `action` struct.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Maybe have `action move() { action result; result.setup("*"); return result; }`?

Comment: thanks, @Eljay Now I understand the difference between functions and objects

Comment: Then, what are the benefits of using `action` as the function type except that it could return an `action`? Can it use any of the member functions when calling `action move` eg. `move().wait();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters the function `setup` is a non-static member function of the class `action`. It can be used applied to an object of the class. And the function `move` returns nothing though it has the return type `action`.

The function `move` can look like

```
action move()
{
    action a;

    a.setup("*");

    return a;
}
```